# PHP check if string contains brackets

Tags: php, function, brackets

I just want to build a php function that checking if string is contain brackets and return boolean, anyone can help?

example:

```
$string = "{hallo}"; // true
$string2 = "h{allo}"; //true
$string3 = "hal}{o"; //false
$string4 = "hallo{}";//false
```

Comment: In stackoverflow you're supposed to do some kind of searching before asking :-) I'm sorry, but this does not look like an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
<?php

$string = "{hallo}"; 

$res = preg_match('/{\w+}/',$string);

print_r($res);

?>
```